# Adobe Animate iOS app >WARNING ITMS-90722: "Certificate Expired. The signing certificate has expired?

Tags: ios, air, adobe-animate

Just came across this warning message while uploading an existing AIR App compiled using Adobe Animate iOS app. Uploaded with Apple Application Loader. I am using the latest AIR (30beta and have tried stable) and XCODE 9.3.1, Adobe Animate 2017.

> WARNING ITMS-90722: "Certificate Expired. The signing certificate "CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations, O=Apple Inc., C=US" with serial number 25 used to sign .app has expired. Learn more (https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09)."

I checked the link, logged into Xcode to check if any missing keys. All looks fine. Then I re-setup a completely new CSR, p12, provisioning profiles etc everything from scratch uploaded the new compiled Test-App - still says the same thing?

**Image from URL above -**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. However I am using AIR 29 and compiling with IntelliJ IDE. I also created new certs, provisioning, and .p12 files and linked with my current build.

I was forced to update from AIR 26 with the latest requirements from apple to support iOS 11.x.  In order to get onto XCode 9.x (required for creating the Assets.car file), I had to also upgrade my OS version.  So in this process I had some issues with keys that got lost and had to create several new entries in KeyChain. XCode doesn't play nice on upgrade either. Had to revoke keys, clean project, restart Xcode and OS... Basically a pain in the @%$#.

I had reached a point where I was having missing keys and my build would get rejected. After fixing that, I'm just getting the same warning as you, which seems only to be a warning at the moment and not a rejection.

Good thing is at least the build is making it up for deployment.  Not sure if this is something on Apple's end or Adobe's.

Comment: thanks for the response, are you saying that its related to the Assets.car file? I have tried AIR/28/29 its the same issue ATM (warning), yes they are uploading fine I will be submitting this update soon so I guess time will tell if a rejection or not. They seemed to have updated something on Apple's side to cause this Warning nothing has changed on my Certs so it's very strange. Hopefully, Adobe will release an AIR update to fix this error. Please message back if you find an answer.

Comment: I previously updated an App that was published on Itunes with AIR 28 and used the same certs p12/provisioning profiles (with the new Assets.car requirement) - Never saw this error warning before. Now 2 months down the line I am seeing this new Warning (same certs/p12 used etc).

Comment: No, the the file specifically, but obviously there is something different with the enforcement of iOS 11.x support.   However, like I mentioned, my OS update and XCode update to be current botched a lot of my keys in my keychain.  I had to basically reset all keys. So it's hard to say exactly what the issue is. However, since I now have all fresh keys and certs, it might be an Apple issue... But I can only speculate.

Comment: You might want to post in the Starling Forum.  Make sure to link to this post.  Those guys are pretty sharp with some of these OS issues.  Josh has been a real help for me on certain occasions, dealing with issues more related to setup and tools rather than Starling or Feathers.

Answer (score 0):

The AIR 30 SDK solve this problem.

Cheers Stefan